# Code Signing Windows Metro App

Tags: microsoft-metro, digital-certificate

I purchased a Comodo Code Signing Certificate, and when I select that in my Metro app, and build, I get

> Error 4  File content does not conform to specified schema. The `'Publisher'` attribute is invalid - The value `'CN=Falafel Software Inc, O=Falafel Software Inc, STREET="512 Capitola Ave,", L=Capitola, S=CA, PostalCode=95010, C=US'` is invalid according to its datatype `'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest:ST_Publisher'` - The Pattern constraint failed.
>
> ```
> C:\Users\jwaters\documents\visual studio 11\Projects\App1\App1\bin\Debug\AppxManifest.xml
> 10 57  App1
> ```

I found this more detailed message

> `'CN=Falafel Software Inc, O=Falafel Software Inc, STREET="512 Capitola Ave,", L=Capitola, S=CA, PostalCode=95010, C=US'` violates pattern constraint of `'(CN|L|O|OU|E|C|S|STREET|T|G|I|SN|DC|SERIALNUMBER|(OID\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))+))=(([^,+="<>#;])+|".*")(, ((CN|L|O|OU|E|C|S|STREET|T|G|I|SN|DC|SERIALNUMBER|(OID\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))+))=(([^,+="<>#;])+|".*")))*'`. The attribute `'Publisher'` with value `'CN=Falafel Software Inc, O=Falafel Software Inc, STREET="512 Capitola Ave,", L=Capitola, S=CA, PostalCode=95010, C=US'` failed to parse.

It looks like the regexp doesn't understand `PostalCode`, which is in my certificate's Subject.

Is there any way to get around this?